# Displaying task name after executing it

Tags: ansible

I have a task to install the OS patch like this.  When I run this playbook, it displays task name after executing the task.  For a few minutes, I see only a blank screen.

Is there a way to display the task name, while starting the job?

```yaml
- name: Updating all packages
  yum:
    name: '*'
    state: latest
    disable_gpg_check: yes
```

Comment: It should display the task name  *before* executing the task. E.g., when I run the above task, I see `TASK [Updating all packages] ***` printed immediately to the console, and then nothing while all the updates are applied. What version of ansible are you using, and in what environment are you running it?

Comment: Are you using a specific stdout callback such as skippy in ansible.cfg? Callbacks having to prune output based on condition will cache the result output until they can decide to print it or not.

Comment: yes, I have `stdout_callback = yaml` setting in my ansible.cfg file.

Comment: And so..... What happens if you go back to default?

Answer (score 0):

> ***... it displays task name after executing the task. For a few minutes, I see only a blank screen. ...***

This is default and expected behavior depending on some configuration parameters.

```bash
~/test$ cat /etc/redhat-release
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.9 (Maipo)
~/test$ ansible --version
ansible [core 2.11.12]
  config file = /home/ansible_user/test/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = [u'/home/ansible_user/.ansible/plugins/modules', u'/home/ansible_user/.ansible/collections/ansible_collections']
  ansible python module location = /home/ansible_user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible
  ansible collection location = /home/ansible_user/.ansible/collections:/usr/share/ansible/collections
  executable location = /home/ansible_user/.local/bin/ansible
  python version = 2.7.5 (default, May 30 2023, 03:38:55) [GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-44)]
  jinja version = 2.11.3
  libyaml = True
```

For a

**`ansible.cfg`**

```ini
display_skipped_hosts   = False
stdout_callback         = yaml
```

a minimal example playbook

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - name: Long running task (pause)
    pause:
      seconds: 5
```

will result into an output of

```yaml
PLAY [localhost] ******************************************
Pausing for 5 seconds
(ctrl+C then 'C' = continue early, ctrl+C then 'A' = abort)

TASK [Long running task (pause)] **************************
[localhost]

PLAY RECAP ************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1
```

whereby with a

```ini
show_per_host_start     = True
display_skipped_hosts   = False
stdout_callback         = yaml
```

the output result would be

```yaml
PLAY [localhost] ******************************************
 [started TASK: Long running task (pause) on localhost]
Pausing for 5 seconds
(ctrl+C then 'C' = continue early, ctrl+C then 'A' = abort)

TASK [Long running task (pause)] **************************
ok: [localhost]

PLAY RECAP ************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1
```

> ***Is there a way to display the task name, while starting the job?***

In short, yes. In any case via an `ansible.cfg` parameter of `show_per_host_start = True`.

**Similar Q&A and Documentation**

- [Ansible: Print task header before executing a long running task](https://serverfault.com/a/1078749/448950)
- [`default` callback – default Ansible screen output - Parameter: `show_per_host_start`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/default_callback.html#parameter-show_per_host_start)